# How to get the sales per month?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, for-loop, element

I have an array with [365] element which stores the sales per day. My question is how can I sort these days into the 12 months?

Comment: Not all years have 365 days, mind.

Comment: What do you mean "Sort" into months? Create 12 arrays, one for each month?

Comment: The "sales per day" starting when?

Comment: Provide data sample or we can't help all

Comment: I know, not all years have 365 days, but my task now is to only determine year which has 365 year.
So I think I should create one array with 12 element, which represent the total sale per month. One array element represents the total sale of one month.
The first sales per day starts with the first day of a year.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your question is like this:

```
     public class SalesInfo
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public Array GetSalesByMonth(SalesInfo[] items)
    {
        return items.GroupBy(x => x.Day.Month).Select(x => new
        {
            Month=x.Key,
            SalesValue=x.Sum(a=>a.Value)
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your sales are running using some sort of Julian date format (probably a truncated form) where 0 is equivalent to January 1st.

You'll need to know the year - so that you can calculate whether you are in a leap year or not, in which case you'll need 366 days not 365. There are algorithms available.

You'll also need to know how many days there are in each month, allowing for the extra day for February in a leap year.

You then index through your sales figures, adding the elements as you go, placing the result wherever you are storing your result for that month, until you have indexed into the next month e.g. index = 0 for January 1st, index = 31 for February 1st. Remember to reset your result to 0 at the beginning of each month.